# PATH Export Behavior With Same File In Two Locations

Tags: bash

Numerous posts online state to add a new path to the end of your existing $PATH value to ensure that any regular system paths are prioritized first (It is also written in Steve Parkers "Shell Scripting" book).  So I tested this to see what happens if I had 2 new directories added to my path, with both having the same filename in with 755 permissions.

```
$ cat /home/john/testpath1/aaa
echo "hi from testpath1/aaa"
$ cat /home/john/testpath2/aaa
echo "hi from testpath2/aaa"
$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/john/testpath1:/home/john/testpath2
$ aaa
hi from testpath1/aaa
```

Sure enough, I got the result I was expecting, showing that it's prioritised the testpath1 directory over testpath2's directory.  Good. Now I want to test to see what happens when I delete this file, to ensure the aaa file in testpath2 gets executed:

```
$ rm /home/john/testpath1/aaa
$ aaa
bash: /home/john/testpath1/aaa: No such file or directory
```

I was not expecting this, since the file is definately there. So why doesn't it find it? It's like it's cached the first path file or something..?  Anyways I validate that the file definately executes and works if the testpath1 directory is removed, and it does:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/john/testpath1:/home/john/testpath2
$ export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/john/testpath2
$ aaa
hi from testpath2/aaa
```

So clearly the aaa file in testpath2 works, but can only be found once I remove testpath1..?

Can someone explain why aaa is removed from testfile1, that the aaa file in testfile2 does not get found?

Comment: The shell has a cache of locations of programs. Use `hash -r` to clear it when you uninstall programs.

Comment: If this were a script, the cache would be specific to each copy of the script, so a second copy would be starting from a blank set of hashed paths and finding only the `testpath2` copy of your executable. As such, it's a problem one generally hits with _interactive_ shells, which aren't on-topic on Stack Overflow; interactive shell usage and configuration is more a topic for [unix.se], whereas SO's scope is narrowly focused on software development.